# How to show the progress bar in raster calc function?

Tags: r, progress-bar, r-raster, calc

how I can use the progress bar like [this example](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html) inside of a function written for use for use in calc raster function?

I have a huge dataset to process and I desire to use the progress bar to control the duration of process. I tryied to use like this, the function (of process) works prefectly, but, do not show the progress bar.

```
# PROGRESS BAR IN CALC RASTER EXAMPLE
# create data
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10) 
dataset <- list() 
for (i in 1:20) { 
    dataset[i] <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3) ) 
} 
dataset <- stack(dataset)

## function to apply
pixel <-getValuesBlock(s1, row=1, nrows=1, col=1, ncols=1, lyrs=1:nlayers(s1))
CropAnalysis <- function (pixel, ...){
 gc()
 pb <- txtProgressBar(...)
 # test : if is No data the return is 
 if (identical(x = is.na(pixel), y = rep(TRUE,length(pixel)))) {NA}else{
 averageOfhigher <- mean(pixel[pixel > 10], na.rm=T)
 averageOflower <- mean(pixel[pixel < 10], na.rm=T)
 return(c(averageOfhigher, averageOflower))
 }
 setTxtProgressBar(pb)}

 # applying calc finction
 data_process<-calc(x=dataset, fun=CropAnalysis, forcefun=TRUE, forceapply=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `progress` argument that is build in to most functions in the `raster` package. It is only shown when writing in chunks (because the dataset is large).

```
# example data
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10) 
d <- stack(lapply(1:20, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3) )) )

f  <- function(pixel, ...){
     if (all(is.na(pixel))) {
        c(NA, NA) # note the two NAs to match the other case 
     } else {
        averageOfhigher <- mean(pixel[pixel > 10], na.rm=TRUE)
        averageOflower <- mean(pixel[pixel < 10], na.rm=TRUE)
        c(averageOfhigher, averageOflower)
     }
  }
```

Do not use the line below in a script. It is only needed in this
toy example to trigger writing in chunks such that the progress bar appears

```
rasterOptions(todisk=TRUE)
```

But do use the `progress` argument (either "text" or "window")

```
r <- calc(d, fun=f, progress='text')
```

Comment: HI @RobertH, I apply your suggestion  and there is no progress bar, only the start and the end of progress. How to fix this?

Comment: that suggest there is not much data. You can set a smaller chunksize in rasterOptions to get more steps (but that may slow things down a bit)

Comment: when I use progress="text" the console presents only " |                |0%" all time, but, when I apply progress="window" present a windown from tcltk package as the progress.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution 
you can use the `rasterOptions` function that is built in the raster package.

 as an example 
`rasterOptions(progress = 'text',timer=TRUE)` will show you the progress, as the example you showed, and the time for each used function from the raster package.

 check this link for more advanced options:
https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/rasterOptions.html